# Changing the stereo camera angle in PR2 simulation

Tags: simulation, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I was going through pick and place tutorial for PR2 robot (in simulation).

I noticed that /narrow_stereo(_textured) angle (in gazebo and rviz) got set such that now it covers things at a distance (previously it was set such that it was covering a part of its base and the table). In this setting it is unable to pick anything as all the objects which it detects are out of its reach.

How can I change the angle of the stereo camera (probably that requires changing the head angle)??

I am able to move arm around using the tutorial : http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/Teleop%20PR2%20arm%20in%20simulation

and launch file : http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/yaml-file-for-CartesianPoseController-JTTeleop-etc-td1396230.html

But I do not understand what exactly is happening in the launch file. I guess I might be able to solve the problem if I understand this completely.

I think error posted at :[ http://answers.ros.org/question/31995/how-to-solve-tabletop-detection-returned-error/?answer=36455#post-id-36455 ] could also be because of this.

Any help/pointers is greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36680/changing-the-stereo-camera-angle-in-pr2-simulation/) by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2012-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello !

I think that tutorial could help you : [moving head](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Moving%20the%20Head).

---

Originally posted by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) with karma: 697 on 2012-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2012-06-18**:
Hey Erwan, Thanks a lot, This nice tutorial explains, why I was not getting any similar question on the forum. :-)